# clearinterval on document.ready

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

hello im new to javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            Dashboard("<?php echo base_url();?>Kasir/display")
            var again = setInterval(function(){Dashboard("<?php echo base_url();?>Kasir/display")},2000);
        }
    )
    function klik2(){
        alert('jwqeoiqej');
        clearInterval(again);
    }
</script>
```

my alert works but i dunno why my clearinterval doesnt seems to work when i run that function

Comment: `again` is only defined inside the `ready` function. It does not exist in `klik2`.

Comment: so i have to defined outside it?

Comment: How is `klik2` called? Because if I had to guess I'd say you have it as an inline event handler on some HTML element. Which is a bad idea. If you did it "properly" then you could attach the event handler inside the `ready` function and that way `again` would be in scope.

Comment: You need to call the klik2 function, also there is no setInterval

Comment: yes i had it in onclick event.

Comment: i dunno how to javascript, i need that ready function to load and set interval to it when first load page, and when the button is clicked the interval is gone